# DOM Parser for reading XML File(edit)

Tags: java, dom

I want to read following XML file using DOM Parser.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CCL>
    <COUNTRY>
       <COUNTRYNAME>INDIA</COUNTRYNAME>
        <CITY>
            <CITYNAME>NOIDA</CITYNAME>
            <LOCALITY>SEC 22^SEC 24^SEC 55</LOCALITY>
        </CITY>
        <CITY>
            <CITYNAME>DELHI</CITYNAME>
            <LOCALITY>MAYUR VIHAR^PATPARGANJ^CHANDNI CAHUK</LOCALITY>
        </CITY>
    </COUNTRY>
    <COUNTRY>
       <COUNTRYNAME>SINGAPORE</COUNTRYNAME>
        <CITY>
            <CITYNAME>TIONG BAHRU</CITYNAME>
            <LOCALITY>BLK 150^BLK 154^BLK 129</LOCALITY>
        </CITY>
        <CITY>
            <CITYNAME>TANJONG PAGAR</CITYNAME>
            <LOCALITY>MAXWELL ROAD^CECILL STREET^AXA TOWER</LOCALITY>
        </CITY>
    </COUNTRY>
</CCL>
```

and my java code is

```
public void ReadXMlFile(File f) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException
    {    
                log.info("Reading log file" + f.getName() + ", from:  "+ f.getAbsolutePath());      
                File fXmlFile = f;
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                log.info("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY");
                log.info("-----------------------");

                for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                   Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                   if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                      Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                      log.info("COUNTRYNAME: " + getTagValue("COUNTRYNAME", eElement));

                        NodeList nodel= eElement.getChildNodes();
                        for(int tempcity=0; tempcity< nodel.getLength() ; tempcity++)
                        {
                            Node nNode_1 = nodel.item(tempcity);
                    if (nNode_1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement_1 = (Element) nNode_1;

     log.info("CITYNAME: " + getTagValue("CITYNAME", eElement));
    log.info("LOCALITY: " + getTagValue("LOCALITY", eElement));

                               }


                        }



                   }

                }

    }

private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
            NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

                Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

            return nValue.getNodeValue();
          }
```

I m getting followin output

```
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:41) - Root element :CCL
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:43) - -----------------------
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:52) - COUNTRYNAME: INDIA
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:61) - CITYNAME: NOIDA
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:62) - LOCALITY: SEC 22^SEC 24^SEC 55
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:61) - CITYNAME: NOIDA
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:62) - LOCALITY: SEC 22^SEC 24^SEC 55
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:61) - CITYNAME: NOIDA
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:62) - LOCALITY: SEC 22^SEC 24^SEC 55
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:52) - COUNTRYNAME: SINGAPORE
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:61) - CITYNAME: TIONG BAHRU
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:62) - LOCALITY: BLK 150^BLK 154^BLK 129
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:61) - CITYNAME: TIONG BAHRU
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:62) - LOCALITY: BLK 150^BLK 154^BLK 129
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:61) - CITYNAME: TIONG BAHRU
 INFO [http-8080-1] (UtilityClass.java:62) - LOCALITY: BLK 150^BLK 154^BLK 129
```

I want to read all entries in CITY tag for every country.

**

> I am able to read the country tag, but I am not sure how to read CITY,
>   CITYNAME for every entry of country. Please help me

**

Can any one help me to resolve this issue

Comment: What *are* you getting? In other words, describe the problem. (I'm not convinced `nNode23` is a good variable name.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just referencing the wrong `Element` from your CITYNAME & LOCALITY log messages..

Try changing from:

```
 if (nNode_1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement_1 = (Element) nNode_1;

     log.info("CITYNAME: " + getTagValue("CITYNAME", eElement));
    log.info("LOCALITY: " + getTagValue("LOCALITY", eElement));

 }
```

To:

```
 if (nNode_1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement_1 = (Element) nNode_1;

     log.info("CITYNAME: " + getTagValue("CITYNAME", eElement_1));
    log.info("LOCALITY: " + getTagValue("LOCALITY", eElement_1));

 }
```

I can't be sure because I can't see the definition of getTagValue(..), but it looks very likely

HTH